# Can I get the information as soon as a user adds an activity to Google Fit?

Tags: android, google-fit

According to Google Fit SDK example, I query a session in a week but it return only information created by my app only.

```
private SessionReadRequest readFitnessSession() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    // Build a session read request
    SessionReadRequest readRequest = new SessionReadRequest.Builder()
            .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .read(DataType.TYPE_SPEED)
            .setSessionName(SAMPLE_SESSION_NAME)
            .build();
    // [END build_read_session_request]

    return readRequest;
}
```

How can I get all of activity in a period? Need I build a release app?

And is there any event listener or intent when user add an activity in Google Fit?

Answer (score 0):

This is answer for 1st question. How to read from all apps : [readSessionsFromAllApps](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/request/SessionReadRequest.Builder.html#readSessionsFromAllApps())